# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

Let be $x_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}(1-x)^{n}dx$. Find $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}$. I proved that $\lim_{n \to \infty }x_{n}=0$ and I tried to use l'Hospital

Comment: Try to find about beta integral. It'll be helpful.

Comment: I have a method without using beta-function. Just elementary integration. Should I? (If you don't know about beta-function)

Comment: @Dior Yes I will. When I reach home, I'll type it out and post an answer.

Comment: @Dior Sorry Dior, While typing out the solution, I recognised a mistake in my solution. It can not be solved using elementary integrals.

Answer (score 3):

$x_n=\beta(n+1,n+1)=\frac{n!~~ n!}{(2n+1)!},~~~~~~~$ (Beta function)

So, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n+1)!~~(n+1)!}{(2n+3)!}\times \frac{(2n+1)!}{n!~~ n!}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n+1)~~(n+1)}{(2n+3)~~(2n+2)}=\frac{1}{4}$.